# UI Router: Access route directly using the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I thought this would be a really common problem, but I can't find anything about this. I have two states one is accessed on `/route` and the second one on `/route/{name}`. It works fine if I call the second route using `ui-sref` but when I refresh the page or try to access it directly via url I get on the `/route` page even tough the url in the browser stays the same. How do I fix that?

```
  function Routes($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state("route1", {
      url: "/route",
      templateUrl: "js/route/route1.html",
      controller: "Route1Controller",
      controllerAs: "vm",
      resolve: {
        ...
      }
    })
    .state("route2", {
      url: "/route/{name}",
      templateUrl: "js/route/route2.html",
      controller: "Route2Controller",
      controllerAs: "vm",
      resolve: {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
```

**Edit:** To make it more clear, I would like that `route2` acts like any other state with a complete different url. I guess nobody would suggest nested views if the urls where "/route1" and "/route2". If that's not possible I will consider using a nested view in the `route1` template.

**Edit2:** The problem was not with the posted code. I had another route "/route/:id" but I didn't define the type. Therefore the routes where actually the same. I defined the types ("/route/{id:int}") and now it works.

Comment: It would be nice if you declare route1 as parent and route2 as child, in that case name your child state something like route1.name

Comment: I tried that, but they are two different pages, when I declare route2 as child it doesn't load the template.

Comment: did u change url when ur using child route

Comment: because your url should be url:/{name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **order** of state definition decides in this case. The `UI-Router` will iterate all defined states and try to find the one - which matches to **current url**. And the first match will decide.

So we just have to declare the scond one as the first:

```
$stateProvider
// this will be defined as the first 
.state("route2", {
  url: "/route/{name}",
  ...
  }
})
// if no match for /route/param
// this will be used
.state("route1", {
  url: "/route",
  ...
});
```

Comment: Is it a recommended method, I dont think so. He should be using nested views. The above methods is ok if he is using ng-route if I am not wrong

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work. Maybe the parameter doesn't get recognized at all.

Comment: If you are intereseted in this approach, can show you in a plunker. Let me know

Comment: Yes I am very interested, but I created a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/aClMVdnrmr7M5hz2OPkN?p=preview to show it doesn't work in my case, but I don't know how to test it, because I can't see the url, reload the page or access it directly.

Comment: The mistake was somewhere else - see above.

Answer (score 1):

have u tried this, change the state and url to below

```
$stateProvider
    .state('route1', {            
        url: '/contacts',
    })
    .state('route1.name', {            
        url: '/{name}'
        //...more
    })
```

Comment: I tried it before and now again. The url changes, resolve gets executed and loaded but I don't see the new template.

Comment: are u using ui-view inside route1.html ?

Comment: for reference https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: sorry was out for a moment. Is this really the correct way? I know I could use nested views with ui-view inside the template of route1 but it technically is not a nested view. Even tough the url suggests it, it should be its own view/state.

Comment: If its not a nested view, then u should use different url, your url declaration sounds like nested view though. Angular would felt the same too, thats y its url is not changing to /route/{name} because it gets mapped to /route anyway.

Comment: If its not the nested view, then I suggest you to go with Radim Kohler solution

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$stateProvider.state("route1", {
  url: "/route",
  templateUrl: "js/route/route1.html",
  controller: "Route1Controller",

})
.state("route1.name", {
  url: "/{name}",
  templateUrl: "js/route/route1-name.html",
  controller: "Route1NameController",
});
```

And in your index.html file :

```
<body>
    ...
    <div ui-view></div>
    ...
</body>
```